# how to implement scd type 2 with type1 in spark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have requirement  to capture old records along with new changes in  azure databricks notebook.
ex:

```py
|----------------------------------------------------------------------
|EMPNO       ROW_EFF_DT     STATE_CODE      CITY_NAME     ROW_EXPIRY_DT
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1550    19-10-2020      TA            FORTWORTH          20-10-2020  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1550    20-10-2020      TX             RONOLE            21-1-2020    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1550    21-1-2020      TX             GRAPEVIN            NULL         |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
I hope given useful information,Please feel free to ask if need some more info.


Any inputs for the above scenario will be helpful.
```

Comment: Could you add more information so that other can better help you?

Comment: you want type 1 or type 2 ?

Comment: @Steven, I am looking for  maintaining history along with current rows as i shown above in my table.